Does AutoML Image Object Detection cost less or more than AutoML Video Intelligence using object tracking?
I'm planning to use either for object tracking. If it's object detection via image, I can probably just pass 1 frame/second and run the image model on it to classify and draw bounding boxes. This will work together with a Video Intelligence Action Tracking model which will essentially be able to detect crimes. Which is the more cost-effective solution?
